# What is meant by May?

Tags: meaning

> I agree, it might have been better to leave Thor out of this, but as I said, I am a bit hot-tempered - impulsive shall we call it? There was a grumble and a rumble, a few thunderbolts which Thor liked to throw for fun, and then a flash of lightning. Thor stood in front of me, towering with rage, and swinging his hammer about. It really was time to go. “Curse the lot of you,” I cried “**May you and yours be consumed in the endless Fire both now and at the end of days!”**

> is this a question sentence ?